# Nothing in the Emulation tab on IE 11

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, ie-developer-tools

I recently update to IE11. I would like to use develop tool for change the browser to previous version for testing and comparison. I searched the website [How to get your ASP.NET application working in IE11](http://blogs.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/posts/13-12-19/how-to-get-your-asp.net-application-working-in-ie11) to use emulation tab but there is nothing for my IE. Would someone tell me how can I have it.

The following screenshot is my IE 11
[image: DOM Explorer]

[image: Emulation tab]

Comment: This is a bug in the developer tools; I thought it was already taken care of (it crept up on me a couple times in development), but it apparently still has a way of surfacing. I'll file an issue internally and see if we can have it fixed a.s.a.p. Does a browser-restart resolve this?

Comment: @JonathanSampson, I restart the browser, it didn't fixed.

Comment: I have reported the issue and will let you know of any follow up.

Comment: Other users who have experienced this issue are finding that installing all updates as of today (including recommended updates) through Windows Update resolves the issue. Can you try running Windows Update, installing all updates, and then checking to see if the issue still repros?

Comment: To get the emulation mode in the F12 developer tools for IE11 working, I had to install 2 security updates for IE11 from windows update. Then I had to restart my computer.

Comment: @Sampson I'm having this issue. What KB fixes it?

Comment: @Zeno I'm not; which build of Windows do you happen to be on? You can run `winver` from the Run Dialog to determine this.

Comment: @Sampson Windows 7 (6.1 build 7601 SP1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After run the update windows, the issue is gone.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue for one of my applications recently.

I fixed it the other way. Posting it here might help someone.

1. In IE, navigate to Settings --> Compatibility View Settings --> Add this website.
2. Enter your website URL & Click Add & then Close.
3. Now open your app in IE & this issue will be gone.